# How to properly align label and text field in iOS/Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to align multiple elements in my view controller so that they align properly on different screen sizes. At the moment, I have headings (in blue) with labels and text fields in line. From the research I've done it seems that using constraints is the way to go. However, in all the examples I have seen, none seem to explain how to properly add/adjust these constraints if the elements are of different sizes.

Take for example the attached image. I can successfully use constraints to align labels 1, 2 and 3 vertically and horizontally. However, Text Field 1 is not only larger (in height) than label 2 but it also doesn't have the same neighbor as Label 2 (the constraints for label 2 use label 1 as their neighbor whereas it seems the closest neighbor for Text Field 1 is the top most margin). Furthermore, label 4 will have a similar issue because the size of its closes neighbor (Text field 1) is larger than that of label 3 (whose closes neighbor is label 2).

So far I've been able to set the relative positioning of these elements in the storyboard so that they are all visible on all screen sizes but that's inefficient and produces wasted space on the right hand side of the screen on larger screens.

Can anyone offer suggestions how to achieve this? I'm assuming there is a simple way to do this within the storyboard but haven't figured it out yet.

[Xcode screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxtIG.png)

Comment: The screenshot does not seem to include a text view.

Comment: No law requires you to configure constraints in the storyboard or even to use a storyboard. I recommend learning to set up layout in code. It lets you specify easily what aligns to what and how, and it's a lot easier to discuss and describe on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @matt That first paragraph should have read text field, not text view. I've corrected it. The rest of the question does correctly read Text Field though. Wouldn't I run into the same issue when defining the constraints in code though? The size of the Text Fields when rendered is larger than labels, so how does one go about setting the right constraints? I've considered taking into account the size of the rendered text fields but in practice that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You can use a baseline constraint to align the baseline of the label with the baseline of the text field.

Comment: "I've corrected it." You haven't.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you for the suggestion of baseline constraints. I'll take a look at them and give them a try.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to provide leading alignment to *label1*, *label2* and *label3* and you want to align textField1 horizontally to the *label2* and *label4* to *label3*.

Here is how you can achieve this in code:

```
    func activateConstraints() {
      label1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      label2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      label3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      textField1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      label4.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

      label1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
      label1.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true

      label2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label1.topAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
      label2.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label1.leadingAnchor).isActive = true

      label3.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label2.topAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
      label3.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label2.leadingAnchor).isActive = true

      textField1.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
      textField1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 35).isActive = true
      textField1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 75).isActive = true
      textField1.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label2.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

      label4.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textField1.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
      label4.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label3.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    }
```

Of course this is a large method, and in your production code, you might want to refactor it into many smaller methods.

Also, please note that *view* is your view controller's main view.